# Compare Size of Arrays Inside an Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to `find` all documents where `sCompetitions.length` is greater than `competitions.length`.

Here's some sample documents document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b28f432b4353d3f311dd1b"),
    "name" : "Ford Focus RS 2008",
    "requirements" : [ 
        {
            "rankType" : "D1",
            "competitions" : [ 
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116827"), 
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116829")
            ],
            "sCompetitions" : [ 
                "Rallye Monte-Carlo", 
                "Rally Sweden"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "rankType" : "A3",
            "competitions" : [
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116f6b")
            ],
            "sCompetitions" : [ 
                "Rally Italia Sardegna", 
                "Neste Rally Finland"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("0000b28f432b4353f311dd1b"),
    "name" : "Ford Focus RS 2012",
    "requirements" : [ 
        {
            "rankType" : "D1",
            "competitions" : [ 
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116827"), 
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116829")
            ],
            "sCompetitions" : [ 
                "Rallye Monte-Carlo", 
                "Rally Sweden"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "rankType" : "A3",
            "competitions" : [
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116f6b"),
                ObjectId("59b151fd2b4353d3f3116f6b")
            ],
            "sCompetitions" : [ 
                "Rally Italia Sardegna", 
                "Neste Rally Finland"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So looking at the samples it would only return `ObjectId("59b28f432b4353d3f311dd1b")`

My problem is that `requirements` is an array by itself, so I would need to somehow iterate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to "iterate". All you really need is an [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) check after returning results from [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/). And you can do this all inside a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) action:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$requirements",
            "as": "r",
            "in": { 
              "$gt": [
                { "$size": "$$r.sCompetitions" },
                { "$size": "$$r.competitions" }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

So it's a simple comparison by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) for each array element, and then if "any" of those elements is `true`, the document is "kept" or otherwise "pruned" from the results.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, could I use an ´OR´ operator inside `in`? Eg. If I want to find all documents where `sCompetitions.length` is greater than `competitions.length` *OR* `rankType == 'CC'`

Comment: @Cornwell You can use whatever you like. The only point here returning a boolean for each array element. This uses [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) because that was the condition you asked for. But any of the [comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) or indeed various others that also return a boolean can be used for the same purpose.